# MS SQL Server 2008: Convert Individual Time Card Entries To Calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I would like to create a time card view from individual time card entries in a SQL table. So the entry table looks something like:

```
LABORID  WORKORDERID  STARTDATE                 HOURS
-----------------------------------------------------
58       13           2014-07-01 00:00:00.000   3.00
58       19           2014-07-07 00:00:00.000   3.00
58       22           2014-07-17 00:00:00.000   8.00
58       34           2014-08-05 00:00:00.000   3.00
58       34           2014-08-05 00:00:00.000   5.00
58       34           2014-08-07 00:00:00.000   8.00
```

I would like to create a view that looks like:

```
LABORID  WORKORDERID  S     M     T     W     T     F     S
-----------------------------------------------------
58       13                       3
58       19                                   3
58       22                                   8
58       34                       8           8
```

I know it's probably going to need a sum, group by and pivot in there but I am at a complete loss. I started down the road of making a calendar table S-S for the next 100 years with the dates in there but I couldn't figure out how to join this information to it.

**UPDATE:**

So I am stuck with the part that I'd like the transactions to be on the same line if they are in the same week. The best answer gives me this:

```
58  34  2014-08-05  NULL    NULL    8.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
58  34  2014-08-07  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5.00    NULL    NULL
```

But I'd like them to be on the same line, because they are in the same week, something like this:

`58    34  2014-08-05  NULL    NULL    8.00    NULL    5.00    NULL    NULL`

Comment: The code sample ({}) is your friend, makes things much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need conditional aggregation:

```
select laborid, workorderid,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, startdate) = 'Sunday' then hours end) as S,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, startdate) = 'Monday' then hours end) as M,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, startdate) = 'Tuesday' then hours end) as T,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, startdate) = 'Wednesday' then hours end) as W,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, startdate) = 'Thursday' then hours end) as T,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, startdate) = 'Friday' then hours end) as F,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, startdate) = 'Saturday' then hours end) as S
from timecardentries
group by laborid, workorderid;
```

Comment: So close! If the transactions are in the same week it doesnt show them on the same line though... Any ideas?

Comment: @mike . . . That doesn't make any sense.  There is no date in the `group by`, so the summary for a given `laborid`/`workorderid` should all be on one row.

Comment: Correct But if the transactions are in the same week on the same work order I would like them to be on the same line. See the comment I attached...

Comment: Your original question explicitly doesn't separate the rows by weeks.  It just summarized by `LaborId` and `WorkOrderId`.  I still don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to determine what day of the week it is, and use a bunch of case statements to get your totals.  You could probably do it with `PIVOT`, but that makes my head hurt.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cfdd/7)

```
select
laborid,
workorderid,
sum (case when datepart(dw,startdate) = 1 then hours else 0 end) as "1",
sum (case when datepart(dw,startdate) = 2 then hours else 0 end) as "2",
sum (case when datepart(dw,startdate) = 3 then hours else 0 end) as "3",
sum (case when datepart(dw,startdate) = 4 then hours else 0 end) as "4",
sum (case when datepart(dw,startdate) = 5 then hours else 0 end) as "5",
sum (case when datepart(dw,startdate) = 6 then hours else 0 end) as "6",
sum (case when datepart(dw,startdate) = 7 then hours else 0 end) as "7"

from timeentry
group by
laborid,
workorderid
```